# How to pass texts to a page?

Tags: templates, view

I'm using python with django.

I have some informative text ("Welcome! This site is about... blabla..." and so on for about 100 lines) to show on a page. It don't change, it don't depend on the user, it isn't interactive... it's just simple plain text.

Maybe it's a stupid question but i'm not sure where it is better to write it: in the `view`, in the `template` or somewhere else? There is difference?

Just now i'm using the template like this:

```
<div>
    <h3 align=center>Title</h3>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
    <p>Another paragraph</p>
    etc etc
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to put this in a template and have a simple view that just renders it.